# how to compile "lightweight-java-profiler" without getting "C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier"

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, c++11

when trying to compile [lightweight-java-profiler](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-06-12/java-flame-graphs.html) with `make all` I get this error:

```
~/tmp/flamejava/lightweight-java-profiler-read-only$ make all
g++ -I/dev/jdk1.7.0/include -I/dev/jdk1.7.0/include/linux -mfpmath=sse -std=gnu++0x -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-exceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -funsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -m64 -msse2 -g -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wvla -Wno-conversion-null -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -Werror -Wformat-security -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-strict-overflow -Wwrite-strings -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -O2 -Fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -c /tmp/flamejava/lightweight-java-profiler-read-only/src/display.cc -o build-64/display.pic.o
/tmp/flamejava/lightweight-java-profiler-read-only/src/display.cc:23:22: error: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Werror=literal-suffix]
       fprintf(file_, "%"PRIdPTR" ", traces[i].count);
                      ^
```

my system:

```
Linux MYMACHINE 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm not sure what to do, how can I fix this problem? and manage to compile it? thanks

Comment: a -1 Isn't the error message clear??

Comment: @T.C. thanks! indeed! i was not sure what it meant by identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"%"PRIdPTR` is being interpreted as a user-defined literal. Add a space before `PRIdPTR`.

Comment: Another solution is to just remove `-std=gnu++0x` flag instead of fixind every similar error manually.